# Can't destroy model until the page is manually reloaded

Tags: ruby, voltrb

I am trying to do something similar to a todo list with story name instead of a todo item.

Model code:

```
class Story < Volt::Model
  validate :name, length: 5

end
```

Controller code:

```
module Main
  class MainController < Volt::ModelController
    model :store

    def index
    end

    def add_story
      new_story = Story.new(name: page._name)
      _stories << new_story
      page._name = ""
    end

    ...
  end
end
```

View code:

```
<:Title>
  Home

<:Body>
  <h1>Home</h1>

  <form e-submit="add_story" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Todo</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ page._name }}" />
    </div>
  </form>

  {{ _stories.each do |story| }}
    <p>{{ story._name}}</p>
    <button e-click="story.destroy">X</button>
  {{ end }}
```

When I add a story name and try to click the delete button, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for #<Story id: "94f1..fc0f", name: "Test">
```

Stack trace for the error:

```
(anonymous function)  @ app.js:3607
Opal.defn.TMP_1 @ app.js:2486
Opal.defn.TMP_2 @ app.js:20321
def.$method_missing.TMP_8 @ app.js:21386
method_missing_stub @ app.js:722
(anonymous function)  @ app.js:18726
def.$destroy  @ app.js:21518
def.$call.TMP_1 @ app.js:13114
(anonymous function)  @ app.js:26485
$a.$$p.TMP_2  @ app.js:26475
Opal.yieldX @ app.js:850
def.$call.TMP_2 @ app.js:13044
$a.$$p.TMP_3  @ app.js:26634
Opal.yield1 @ app.js:830
def.$each.TMP_9 @ app.js:7253
$a.$$p.TMP_2  @ app.js:26634
Opal.defn.TMP_6 @ app.js:3497
def.$handle @ app.js:26639
$a.$$p.TMP_1  @ app.js:26610
jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.0.3.js:4677
elemData.handle @ jquery-2.0.3.js:4361
```

After I reload the page or even if I have another window simultaneously open, I am able to delete the story. So the `#destroy` method doesn't work on the `Story` model until I reload, but I don't understand why and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you give us some stacktrace?

Comment: @Jesper: I added the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this issue was on my end. If you run off of master, this should work now.

`gem 'volt', github: 'voltrb/volt'`